# Pop-up window unwantedly closes after submitting a form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, html, popup

When I try to find a solution to my problem, I only come across people who have the opposite problem of mine.

I'm loading a pop-up div with javascript. Inside the div I'm running a PHP form.
My problem is that whenever I submit the form, my pop-up div automatically closes. I want the pop-up to remain visible while the PHP-echo's display within the pop-up div after submitting.

I'm very new to both javascript and PHP and while I've tried to figure out what goes wrong (I'm assuming the problem sits within my javascript), I can't seem to find out what's wrong.

This is my Javascript, which I got from istockphp.com

```
jQuery(function($) {

$("a.topopup").click(function() {
        loading(); // loading
        setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
            loadPopup(); // function show popup
        }, 500); // .5 second
return false;
});

/* event for close the popup */
$("div.close").hover(
                function() {
                    $('span.ecs_tooltip').show();
                },
                function () {
                    $('span.ecs_tooltip').hide();
                }
            );

$("div.close").click(function() {
    disablePopup();  // function close pop up
});

$(this).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 27) { // 27 is 'Ecs' in the keyboard
        disablePopup();  // function close pop up
    }
});

$("div#backgroundPopup").click(function() {
    disablePopup();  // function close pop up
});

$('a.livebox').click(function() {
    alert('Hello World!');
return false;
});

 /************** start: functions. **************/
function loading() {
    $("div.loader").show();
}
function closeloading() {
    $("div.loader").fadeOut('normal');
}

var popupStatus = 0; // set value

function loadPopup() {
    if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
        closeloading(); // fadeout loading
        $("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
        $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001);
        popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
        actionResponse.setWindowState(LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE);
    }
}

function disablePopup() {
    if(popupStatus == 1) { // if value is 1, close popup
        $("#toPopup").fadeOut("normal");
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("normal");
        popupStatus = 0;  // and set value to 0
    }
}
/************** end: functions. **************/
}); // jQuery End
```

This is my PHP:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: Contactformulier'; 
$to = 'info@mywebsite.nl'; 
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$human = $_POST['human'];

$body = "Afzender:\n $name\n\n E-Mail:\n $email\n\n Onderwerp:\n $subject\n\n Bericht:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
        if ($human == '4') {                 
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
            } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
        echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
    }
    } else {
        echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code you use to submit the form?

Answer (score 1):

Does the page reload and therefore the pop-up closes? If so, you need to prevent the default behavior of the form's submit button.

Comment: It doesn't reload. When I submit my form and re-open the pop-up window, the PHP echo is exactly where I want it to be.

Comment: Jay has the right idea; the popup div closes because of the form submission.

Comment: Any ideas on how to disable that? I've been searching for solutions, but can't really seem to find any that work (or that I can understand ;)

Answer (score 0):

When the form submits, the page reloads.  You basically have two options to prevent the popup from disappearing.

One option, as suggested by Jay Kravetz, is to prevent the default form submission and turn that into an Ajax request.  You'd need to submit to "test2.php":

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
```

Then test2.php would only contain the HTML inside of your "toPopup" div.

Then you'd use a jQuery ajax form submission as described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form) to avoid reloading the page because of the form submission.

The second option is to change test.php so that inside

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
  echo '<div id="popup_content" class="showImmediately">';
  //other logic here
} else {
  echo '<div id="popup_content">';
}
```

Then in your css, add:

```
.showImmediately { display: block !important; }
```

Instead of the CSS, you could also add this at the bottom of your jQuery function:

```
if ($('.showImmediately').length > 0) {
    loading(); // loading
    setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
        loadPopup(); // function show popup
    }, 500); // .5 second
}
```